# How to connect to internet via pppoe by java in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, pppoe

*Hi all
I am a new guy in java and ubuntu.I knew that in windows,i can use rasdial or rasphone to connect to the internet via  pppoe .However,what i face now is ubuntu.so ,my question is that how to use java to connect the internet via  pppoe in ubuntu(not windows,i mean,ubuntu or debian,anyways,linux)

i have found a solution here:

http://code.google.com/p/news-recommender/source/browse/trunk/WeiboCrawler/src/crawler/sina/exe/PPPOE.java?r=706

but it is not what i want as in my computer there are many networkcards(eth0-eth8),and i want to build different pppoe connections in different networkcards(eth0-eth8)......so, how to implement it by java in ubuntu or debian automatically(You know,i mean,without any dial boxes without any manual participations)?

thanks in advance

Comment: what you linked is executing some [shell commands](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13674/how-to-connect-to-the-internet-dsl-automatically-at-startup), if they exist on your system, check how to call them with parameters  that specify the network interface.

Comment: I have found the solution....Share it in here

we can use "pppoe-start" to connect to internet via pppoe

and how to build different connections in different networkcards?u can do it like this:

pppoe-start make use of pppoe.conf .and u can do some configure with the pppoe.conf

my English is very poor ,but if u are not clear with what i say and u need it ,contact me.